# installing urllib in Python 3.6 fails - confusion with Python 2.7

Tags: linux, python

installing urllib in Python3.7 - here i have encountered issues

I would like to import urllib to use the function 'request'.

However, I encountered an error when trying to do so. 
I tried pip install urllib but still had the same error. I am using Python 3.7.x Really appreciate any help. i do import urllib.request using this following code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error 
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt') 
counts = dict()
for line in fhand: 
    words = line.decode().split() 
for word in words: 
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1 
print(counts)
```

but it gives me this error: ModuleNotFoundError:

```
No Module named 'urllib.parse'; 'urllib' is not a package
```

if i look at this page: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

they recomend to install this way:

```
pip install urllib3
```

if i do so i get back this:

```
root@mx:/home/martin# pip install urllib3

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.24.1)
root@mx:/home/martin# ^C
root@mx:/home/martin#
```

well this is funny - since it points out some path to python 2.7

Alternatively, the manpage (https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ) suggests to go this way:  grab the latest source code from GitHub:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/urllib3/urllib3.git
$ python setup.py install
```

this i did not try yet! But i will do so

by the way: i allways thoguth that urllib is a standard python library (built-in) so you don't have to install it.

just import it if you need to use request by:

```
import urllib.request
```

Comment: Try `pip3 install urllib3`

Comment: pip3 install urllib3  worked - many thanks.... it gave back Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.24.1)